# Hierarchical Data frame from a flat dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I having a nested json object, I am able to parse and flatten it to a single level dataframe by preserving hierarchy. Now I need to generate hierarchical data frame need some help on that.

Sample Object:

{"rr":{"bp": {
"0": "0 - 10",
"1": "10 - 20",
"2": "20 - 30"
},
"al": {
"0": 11.8,
"1": 77.2,
"2": 98.4
}}
}

```
flattened Dataframe:
  rr.bp.0  rr.bp.1  rr.bp.2  rr.al.0  rr.al.1  rr.al.2
0  0 - 10  10 - 20  20 - 30     11.8     77.2     98.4

expected hierarchy dataframe 
Header1     Header2 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
rr      bp  0 - 10  10 - 20 20 - 30                      
rr      al  11.8    77.2    98.4
```

**expected hierarchy dataframe**

trying something like this

```
``
for key, value in flattened_data.items():
    keys = key.split(".")
    column_headers = keys[:-1]
    index_label = keys[-1]
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(column_headers)], names=column_headers)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([value],columns=columns)
    temp_df.index = [index_label]
df = pd.concat([df,temp_df])
``
```

but everything is coming as NaN values

Update
I want the output to be dynamic . You can assume that my key names are in order and depth is preserved in flattened dataframe.

Thanks @Timeless. Based on your answer I tried this, it is working
df will be a single level flattened df
example: For this json {"rr":{"bp": { "0": "0 - 10", "1": "10 - 20", "2": "20 - 30" }, "al": { "0": 11.8, "1": 77.2, "2": 98.4 }} }
df will be flattened Dataframe:
rr.bp.0  rr.bp.1  rr.bp.2  rr.al.0  rr.al.1  rr.al.2
0  0 - 10  10 - 20  20 - 30     11.8     77.2     98.4

If more nested keys are there then more dots and keys are added in the same order

```
max_depth = 0
max_depth_list = []
for col in flatten_copy.columns:
    max_depth_list.append(len(re.findall('\.', col)))
max_depth = max(max_depth_list)
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(df).pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.split(".", expand=True), axis=1))
    .stack(list(range(max_depth))).droplevel(0).rename_axis([f"Header{i}" for i in range(max_depth)]).reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected output is ambiguous or at least doesn't match with the title of your question.

I suppose that you're expecting a *DataFrame* like this one :

```
sample_obj = {
    "rr": {
        "bp": {"0": "0 - 10", "1": "10 - 20", "2": "20 - 30"},
        "al": { "0": 11.8, "1": 77.2, "2": 98.4}
          }
}

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(sample_obj).stack()
        .apply(pd.Series) # with a FutureWarning in 2.1.0
        .swaplevel().rename_axis(["Header1", "Header2"]).reset_index()
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  Header1 Header2       0        1        2
0      rr      al    11.8     77.2     98.4
1      rr      bp  0 - 10  10 - 20  20 - 30
```

***UPDATE*** :

If you start from `flattened_data`, you can use this :

```
flattened_data = {
    'rr.bp.0': {0: '0 - 10'},
    'rr.bp.1': {0: '10 - 20'},
    'rr.bp.2': {0: '20 - 30'},
    'rr.al.0': {0: 11.8},
    'rr.al.1': {0: 77.2},
    'rr.al.2': {0: 98.4}
} # which is the result of pd.json_normalize(sample_obj).to_dict()

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(flattened_data)
        .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(
            x.columns.str.split(".", expand=True), axis=1))
        .stack([0, 1]).droplevel(0)
        .rename_axis(["Header1", "Header2"])
        .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Thanks you solution gives me the required output. But I need it to process from flattened dataframe. As I am handling list of arrays also to single level while flattening. Is it possible. Again thanks for the solution

Comment: You're welcome! I update the answer to address your comment. If not, you need to provide a **clear/explicit** input that matches with your actual data.

Comment: your code is working really well. I tried to make it dynamic. Can you check it.
[
`flatten_copy = df.copy()
max_depth = 0
max_depth_list = []
for col in flatten_copy.columns:
 max_depth_list.append(len(re.findall('\.', col)))
max_depth = max(max_depth_list)
df = (
 pd.DataFrame(df).pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.split(".", expand=True), axis=1))
 .stack(list(range(max_depth))).droplevel(0).rename_axis([f"Header{i}" for i in range(max_depth)]).reset_index()
)`
]
Thanks for the Help.

Comment: As said before, you need to provide a clear input and include it to your question.

Comment: You're still not providing a clear input. `flatten_copy` is missing in your question.

Comment: Sorry. flatten_copy will be the flattened_copy of the json object.  That code I cannot share. You can think some thing like this flattened Dataframe:

` rr.bp.0  rr.bp.1  rr.bp.2  rr.al.0  rr.al.1  rr.al.2 \n
0  0 - 10  10 - 20  20 - 30     11.8     77.2     98.4`
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you make the code generic if you can't provide an input. The one you gave in your last comment is what I already used in my update and it is called `flattened_data`. How many dots do you have in the keys ? Always two (*like in* `rr.bp.0`) ? Or they can be arbitrary and not consistent accross the dictionary ? Anyways, you must provide a minimal reproducible input.

Comment: dots will be based on the nested levels of json object. if more objects are there then more keys the column name will be updated with col + "." + key name.

Comment: Sorry but I give up! You updated your question with an input that I used in my first approach (*which is* `sample_obj`).

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. Really appreciate your support. Thanks I will update properly. But for now it is working Thanks